# Text disappears once ARCore loads in Unity app

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am using ARCore on Unity.  I have a canvas in camera space and a text UI component as a child of the canvas to be used to display information to the user while they use the app.  When my app first loads I can see the text on my mobile phone (during the initial loading screens where it says "Unity" and the screen is black).  As soon as the app loads and the camera screen is displayed the text UI component for the most part disappears.  I can still see a gray line where the top of the text should be. I am not doing anything programmatic at runtime to the mesh or anything.  I am updating the actual text value.  I don't see any crashes or errors logged using adb.  Is there something I am missing with using UI and ARCore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Play, switch to Scene view, select your text UI in the hierarchy, on the top menu open GameObject->Align View to Selected.

If you see your text ui in the scene then you know it's still there, just need to figure out why it's not displaying. My guess is it could be a scale issue, where the text ui scales in AR mode.

Start with Canvas Scaler component (attached to your canvas) and set "UI Scale Mode" to "Scale with Screen Size." Then in your Canvas Component (attached to your Canvas) change "Render Mode" to "Screen Space - Overlay."

Comment: So would the suggestion to be to lower the scale of the ui areas (canvas/panel/text)?  I will try your suggestion I get home.

Comment: Yes, many ways to do this. I would start with Canvas Scaler component (attached to your canvas) and set "UI Scale Mode" to "Scale with Screen Size."

Comment: I bet you're right on this and that is why I still see a little gray line when the app is running, it really is my text but super small.  I will try this in a few hours and mark this question as answered by you if it works.  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix my issue.  I added the Canvas Scalar to my canvas component and set UI Scale Mode to Scale with Screen Size.  I get the same effect as before, I can see the text when the app first loads but all but a small gray bar is left when the camera starts.

Comment: A few more things to check:

Comment: Forgot to mention, I did the Align View to Selected and I see the text.  It's almost like when the camera turns on something happens to the canvas or the panel or the text to turn it invisible or transparent except for at the very top because I still see a little gray line where the top of the text should be.

Comment: 1) Canvas->Render Mode->Screen Space Overlay. 2) Try making the text UI and the text font like 100x bigger to test 3) Check scale of UI element while in Play

Comment: Hi, it was the Screen Space Overlay.  I had it set to Screen Space Camera.  Please put that as the answer and I will mark it correct.  Thank you!